# SwiftUI Popup window

Tags: swift, swiftui, popup

I created my first simple card game.

https://codewithchris.com/first-swiftui-app-tutorial/

Now I want to add a pop up window which will pop up with the message "You win" if the player gets 15 points and "You lose" if the CPU gets 15 points first.

Can someone please help me how to do it?
I would be glad if there is some tutorial so I can do it myself, not just copy and paste it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var playCard = "card5"
    @State private var cpuCard = "card9"
    @State private var playerScore = 0
    @State private var cpuScore = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background-plain")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Image("logo")
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Image(playCard)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(cpuCard)
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    //reset
                playerScore = 0
                    cpuScore = 0
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "clock.arrow.circlepath")
                        .font(.system(size: 60))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemRed))                })
                Button(action: {
                    //gen. random betw. 2 and 14
                    let playerRand = Int.random(in: 2...14)
                    let cpuRand = Int.random(in: 2...14)
                    
                   //Update the cards
                    playCard = "card" + String(playerRand)
                    cpuCard = "card" + String(cpuRand)
                
                    //Update the score
                    if playerRand > cpuRand {
                        playerScore += 1
                    }
                    else if cpuRand > playerRand {
                        cpuScore += 1
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image("button")
                })
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Player")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                            
                        Text(String(playerScore))
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("CPU")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                        Text(String(cpuScore))
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your popup like a view. And after that. Call it in method present a view.

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var showingPopup = false // 1
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.opacity(0.2)
            Button("Push me") {
                showingPopup = true // 2
            }
        }
        .popup(isPresented: $showingPopup) { // 3
            ZStack { // 4
                Color.blue.frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                Text("Popup!")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {

    public func popup<PopupContent: View>(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        view: @escaping () -> PopupContent) -> some View {
        self.modifier(
            Popup(
                isPresented: isPresented,
                view: view)
        )
    }
}

public struct Popup<PopupContent>: ViewModifier where PopupContent: View {
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
         view: @escaping () -> PopupContent) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.view = view
    }

    /// Controls if the sheet should be presented or not
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    /// The content to present
    var view: () -> PopupContent
 }
```